# Develop forte UI Button and it's callback using Vuejs and Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, integration, web-frontend

This is one of the way you can try to integrate the forte UI button and its callback.
https://www.forte.net/devdocs/a_checkout/co_product_overview_v2.htm#Coding

The main problem, I was facing at the time of integration is that required a **callback** function globally or outside the Vue object.

So the way to achieve need to make that function global using **window.forteCb**

```
<template>
  <button
    :api_access_id="forteConfig.apiAccessId"
    :version_number="forteConfig.versionNumber"
    :method="forteConfig.method"
    :location_id="forteConfig.locationId"
    :total_amount="forteConfig.totalAmount"
    :utc_time="forteConfig.utcTime"
    :order_number="forteConfig.orderNumber"
    :signature="forteConfig.apiSignature"
    allowed_methods="visa,mast,disc,amex"
    callback = 'forteCb'
    hash_method="sha1"
    save_token="false"
    swipe="false"
    billing_company_name_attr="hide"
  >
    Proceed to Pay
  </button>
</template>
<script>
import { configUrls } from '../../util/clients/client-config';

let self;
const URLS = configUrls();

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
const forteCb = (e) => {
  // console.log(e);
  const response = JSON.parse(e.data);
  // console.log(response);
  switch (response.event) {
    case 'begin':
      // do nothing
      break;
    case 'abort':
      // do nothing
      break;
    case 'success':
      // transaction successful
      self.$emit('forteResponse', `{trace_number: ${response.trace_number} }`);
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
      alert(`Thanks for your order. the trace number is ${response.trace_number}`);
      break;
    case 'failure':
      // handle failed transaction
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
      alert(`Sorry, transaction failed. failed reason is  ${response.response_description}`);
      break;
    default:
      // do nothing
      break;
  }
};

export default {
  name: 'FortePayment',
  data: () => ({
    forteConfig: {},
  }),
  mounted() {
    window.forteCb = forteCb;
    self = this;
    const fortePaymentScript = document.createElement('script');
    fortePaymentScript.setAttribute('src', URLS.FORTE_CHECKOUT);
    document.head.appendChild(fortePaymentScript);
    this.forteConfig = this.$store.state.ForteService.forteConfig;
  },
};
</script>
```